# Writing a program within a program for Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, arduino-ide

I have this project for my final year at college. I chosen to create a device that basically detects motion and perform a task if said motion is detected. This device also has to do this wirelessly through means of Bluetooth.

I'm fairly new to programming but have some understanding of few aspects. I was wondering if there is a statement that is specific for writing a program that if a value is given it reacts with another process.
**As in:**
*In my case, I have a Bluetooth module and a PIR sensor connected to an Arduino board. If motion is detected by the sensor, the sensor sends that information to the board and then the board transmits that information to a device via the Bluetooth module.*
Or am I just overthinking and can simply use an **IF** statement
**Like** : If (PIR detects motion)
Then (Transmit signal through Bluetooth)
Else (Dont transmit or be on stand by)
this is the circuit i ended up with. as reference to what im doing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDwum.jpg)

Edit: I JUST USED AN IF STATEMENT. Im dumb. Thanks for the help btw whoever comments in the future.

Comment: You can just use an if statement

Comment: Yeah, thanks I kind of came to the conclusion that I was overthinking and ended up completing what I wanted to do in 20 minutes. Thanks again :)

Comment: Happens to the best ;)